# Spread syntax not working correctly when applied on generator in Typescript using Visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, generator

When using Visual Studio Code with the following code:

```
function* chain(arrays) {
    for (let i = 0 ; i < arrays.length ; i++)
        yield* arrays[i];   
}
console.log([...chain([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']])]);
```

I get the error:

```
c:\Users\GiladNoy\Desktop\PPLworkspace\ass4\part3\tempCodeRunnerFile.ts:6
console.log([...chain([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']])]);
                                               ^
TypeError: chain(...).slice is not a function
```

However, when I run the same file on cmd using ts-node, the result is as expected:

```
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
```

When not using the ... operator, Visual Studio prints:

```
[ { next: [Function],
    throw: [Function],
    return: [Function],
    [Symbol(Symbol.iterator)]: [Function] } ]
```

And on cmd:

```
[ {} ]
```

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix this problem so that the code on Visual Studio will run the same as when using ts-node on cmd?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the answer, please try.

```
  console.log([...chain,...['A', 'B'], ...['C', 'D']]);
```

Comment: Still not working with error message: "TypeError: chain.concat is not a function".
The problem is probably related to Visual studio itself as the entire print command was taken from our assignment, and is working when run from cmd.